# Texture duplicating opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl, shader

I have a simple function that loads a texture but the problem is when i load 2 textures the second texture is the same as the first texture.

I think it may be a problem with the either the texture loading or rendering?

Texture loading:

```
GLuint loadTexture(std::string path) 
{

    GLuint load;

    glGenTextures(1, &load);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, load);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    float borderColor[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

    glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);


    int tw, th;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image(path.c_str(), &tw, &th, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, tw, th, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return load;
}
```

Rendering and other:

header

```
class TexturedCube {
    static GLuint vbo;
    static GLuint vao;
    bool spec;
    GLuint texture, specular;
    glm::vec3 ambient, diffuse, Lspecular,viewPos;
    float shiny;
public:
    TexturedCube();

    void render(Shader* shader, glm::mat4* model, glm::mat4* view, glm::mat4* projection,glm::vec3 cam);
    void setTexture(std::string path);
    void setSpecular(std::string path);
    void useSpecular(bool x);
    void setAttribs(glm::vec3 amb, glm::vec3 diff, glm::vec3 specs, float shine);
};

GLuint loadTexture(std::string);

const GLfloat cubeverts[] = {
    // Positions           // Normals           // Texture Coords
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

cpp

```
   void TexturedCube::render(Shader * shader, glm::mat4 * model, glm::mat4 * view, glm::mat4 * projection, glm::vec3 cam)
{
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    shader->Use();

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "texture0"), GL_TEXTURE0);

    if (spec)
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, specular);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "texture1"), GL_TEXTURE1);
    }

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(*model));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(*view));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(*projection));

    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "material.shininess"), shiny);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "material.ambient"), ambient.r, ambient.g, ambient.b);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "material.diffuse"), diffuse.r, diffuse.g, diffuse.b);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "material.specular"), Lspecular.r, Lspecular.g, Lspecular.b);
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "viewPos"), cam.x, cam.y, cam.z);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void TexturedCube::setTexture(std::string path)
{
    texture = loadTexture(path);
}

void TexturedCube::setSpecular(std::string path)
{
    specular = loadTexture(path);
    spec = true;
}
```

Frag shader

```
#version 330 core
struct Material {
    sampler2D texture0;
    sampler2D texture1;
    float     shininess;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};  

struct PointLight {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
};

in vec3 FragPos;  
in vec3 Normal;  
in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform Material material;
uniform PointLight light;

void main()
{
    // Ambient
    vec3 ambient = material.ambient * vec3(texture(material.texture0, TexCoords));

    // Diffuse 
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = material.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.texture0, TexCoords));  

    // Specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);  
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = material.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.texture1, TexCoords));

    color = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0f);  

}
```

Then i just call SetSpecular() and SetTexture() then render() in the rendering loop.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the declaration of `texture`?

Comment: GLuint texture, specular;  In the header file.

Comment: Is it a member of some class? Which class? Post a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you are passing wrong values to the uniforms. What you have to do is to pass the texture units index instead of the OpenGL constant. So

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "texture0"), GL_TEXTURE0);
```

has to be changed to

```
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "texture0"), 0);
```

Same for the other texture:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, specular);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader->Program, "texture1"), 1);
```

Comment: Im trying to do some debugging and it looks like to me that the first texture is somehow overwriting the second texture but i have no idea how.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it needs to be qualified "material.texture0" and "material.texture1". Right now you're very likely getting a value of **-1** back for both of those and the uniform struct is assigned the same undefined value for both its `sampler2D` members.